# Горячие клавиши

Tags: winforms, c++, hotkeys

Доброго времени суток. Поискал в инете информация о работе с горячими клавишами в Windows Forms C++ (Visual Studio), ничего путного не нашел (может быть, не так искал), узнал лишь, что назначается горячая клавиша функцией `RegiterHotKey`, затем при нажатии возвращает `WM_HOTKEY`. Собственно вопрос: "Как и где обрабатывать это сообщение?". Если несложно, киньте код (Form1.h), где по нажатию горячей клавиши выполняется какое-то действие. Заранее спс.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему функцией GetAsyncKeyState(); и таймером на 50мс

Comment: Эдак у тебя кашперский будет ругаться, что это клавиатурный шпион :). А вообще же там в ресурсах смотри, в меню (но только не в диалогах, там тоже можно, но дома исходники, ответят еще, наверняка)

Comment: Лицензия стоит - ни слова =)